# obtain the position of elements of Y that a are in X in R

Tags: r, vector, sequence, rows, names

In R,

I have a vector of 5 unique elements:

```
X<-c("A","B","C","D","E")
```

And a vector of repeated elements:

```
Y<- c("A","C","M","Z","B","C","C","R","V","D","D","B","A","V","E","E")
```

I want to obtain the position of elements of Y that a are in X becase Y are rownames of a matrix.

But `Y[match(Y,X)]` gives:

```
[1] "A" "M" NA  NA  "C" "M" "M" NA  NA  "Z" "Z" "C" "A" NA  "B" "B"
```

The response should be:
`c("A","C",NA,NA,"B","C","C",NA,NA,"D","D","B","A",NA,"E","E")`.

to select the rows:

```
Y[-which(is.na(Y[match(Y,X)]))]
```

Is there a better and more elegant alternative?

Answer (score 3):

You can use `%in%`:

```
Y[Y %in% X]
[1] "A" "C" "B" "C" "C" "D" "D" "B" "A" "E" "E"
```

Does this help?

Comment: Yes, it is eqivalent.